# How to skip lines in C files?

Tags: c, file

How to repeat this process every line in the file? What I am doing is that I am reading in names and numbers from files. But I can only do it one line at a time. So I need to skip lines and repeat the process on the next line until I reach the end.

When I do this, it only copies the first line. I am getting the offset every time I read the last name, because I need to get the last name first and it is written after the first name. So I need a reference to go back to the beginning of the line. I used fseek and I use the offset. But it only works on 1 line.

Everything kinda works on 1 line. Assume that the functions I used work fine. Suggestions?

```
number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
//fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
while (number_of_conversions != 0 && number_of_conversions != EOF){
  number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
  if (c == '\n'){
    lines++;
  }
}
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
offset = ftell(fp);
while (j <= lines){
  last_name(fp, string, plength, poffset);
  offset = ftell(fp);
  first_name(fp, string, plength, poffset);
  get_scores(fp, scores);
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    fprintf(fp2, "%c", string[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    fprintf(fp2, "%c", scores[i]);
  }
  fprintf(fp2,"\n");
  j++;
}
```

Comment: I suggest rewriting your code to use `fgets` to read each line into a buffer and then make the processing on that buffer. I would also replace `fscanf("%c")` with `fgetc()` and `fprintf("%c")` with `fputc()`.

Comment: well its too late for that. i already wrote the code. and that would be unnecessary.

Comment: Your not fseek -ing to offset at the end of your while loop. This will put you at the end of last. If the file is first, last and you want the opposite have 2 string variables to read into

Answer (score 0):

To detect the new line you have to read the file as characters as below:-

```
char ch = getc ( fp ); // fp file pointer Or whatever the way you are using //
while ( ch != EOF ) {
    if ( ch == '\n'){// new line has been detected //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code reads the each line as string and you can apply your string operations on this strings. You can use substring function of your own to do the task.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int len;
    char str[2000];
    fptr = fopen("test.txt","r");
    fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_END);
    len=ftell(fptr);
    rewind(fptr);
    while(1)
    {
        fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]",&str);
        if(str!=NULL)
            printf("%s\n",str);
        if(ftell(fptr)==len)
            break;
        fseek(fptr,2,SEEK_CUR);
    }
    fclose(ftpr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why does it have to be strings? cant i do it without them?

Comment: Strings are easy to handle for that reason you can use strings. Also if you have used structure to store the results in file then it will be more efficient and easy way to fetch the data. You can write and read a structure using fread() and fwrite() @Killer_B